# How to transfer only the latest SQL entries from one db to another?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, web

I am running a dev server that i am trying to keep in sync with a live website.

Instead of dropping the dev or live MYSQL database and importing the entire updated db, can I just export and import the most recent changes?

Whats the ideal workflow for keeping databases in sync for developement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your looking for

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html

That has all of the changes and you can just replay them on the other servers. Apart from that replication would be needed

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html